# Argument order to std::min changes compiler output for floating-point

Tags: android, c++, assembly, x86, floating-point

I was fiddling in Compiler Explorer, and I found that the order of arguments passed to std::min changes the emitted assembly.

[Here's the example on Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:5,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Adouble+std_min_xy(double+x,+double+y)+%7B%0A++++return+std::min(x,+y)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adouble+std_min_yx(double+x,+double+y)+%7B%0A++++return+std::min(y,+x)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%235%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:5),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%235,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
double std_min_xy(double x, double y) {
    return std::min(x, y);
}

double std_min_yx(double x, double y) {
    return std::min(y, x);
}
```

This is compiled (with -O3 on clang 9.0.0, for example), to:

```
std_min_xy(double, double):                       # @std_min_xy(double, double)
        minsd   xmm1, xmm0
        movapd  xmm0, xmm1
        ret
std_min_yx(double, double):                       # @std_min_yx(double, double)
        minsd   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
```

This persists if I change the std::min to an old-school ternary operator. It also persists across all the modern compilers I tried out (clang, gcc, icc).

The underlying instruction is `minsd`. Reading the documentation, the first argument of `minsd` is also the destination for the answer. Apparently xmm0 is where my function is supposed to put its return value, so if xmm0 is used as the first argument, there is no `movapd` needed. But if xmm0 is the second argument, then it has to `movapd xmm0, xmm1` to get the value into xmm0.  (editor's note: yes, [x86-64 System V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) passes FP args in xmm0, xmm1, etc., and returns in xmm0.)

My question: why doesn't the compiler switch the order of the arguments itself, so that this `movapd` isn't necessary? It surely must know that the order of arguments to minsd does not change the answer? Is there some side-effect that I'm not appreciating?

Comment: Probably simply because saving a single register swap in a very rare case isn't worth the effort

Comment: @AlanBirtles I would hope that's not how people writing compiler optimizations think. It pains me. I'm trying to make myself not care, because it won't matter in my context, but still it hurts.

Comment: @AlanBirtles:  Rave is correct, that's not how compiler devs think.  If this was really a missed optimization (instead of required by strict FP semantics), gcc and clang developers would probably appreciate having a missed-optimization bug filed.  (Although it would probably already be a known bug; hard-register constraints placed by calling convention requirements do sometimes lead to wasted `mov` or `movaps` instructions when gcc does register allocation, which you wouldn't see in the middle of a larger function after inlining.)

Comment: @bolov I meant that the compiler could have switched the order of the `minsd` operands to save the `movapd`. (But, as I'm learning, it can't do that.)

Comment: why is the android tag added to this question?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**`minsd a,b` is not commutative for some special FP values, and neither is `std::min`**, unless you use `-ffast-math`.

[`minsd a,b`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/minsd) *exactly* implements `(a<b) ? a : b` including everything that implies about signed-zero and NaN in strict IEEE-754 semantics. (i.e. it keeps the source operand, `b`, on unordered<sup>1</sup> or equal).  As Artyer points out, `-0.0` and `+0.0` compare equal (i.e. `-0. < 0.` is false), but they are distinct.

`std::min` is defined in terms of an `(a<b)` comparison expression ([cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)), with `(a<b) ? a : b` as a possible implementation, unlike [`std::fmin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmin) which guarantees NaN propagation from either operand, among other things.  (`fmin` originally came from the C math library, not a C++ template.)

See [What is the instruction that gives branchless FP min and max on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196817/what-is-the-instruction-that-gives-branchless-fp-min-and-max-on-x86) for much more detail about minss/minsd / maxss/maxsd (and the corresponding intrinsics, which follow the same non-commutative rules except in some GCC versions.)

Footnote 1:  Remember that `NaN<b` is false for any `b`, and for any comparison predicate.  e.g. `NaN == b` is false, and so is `NaN > b`.  Even `NaN == NaN` is false.  When one or more of a pair are NaN, they are "unordered" wrt. each other.

| a | b | a < b | `std::min(a,b)` = `minsd a,b` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | false (unordered) | `a` (NaN) |
| NaN | non-NaN | false (unordered) | `a` (NaN) |
| non-NaN | NaN | false (unordered) | `a` (non-NaN); `fmin` would give NaN |
| non-NaN | non-NaN | depends on values | `a` or `b`, the closer to -Inf |
| -0.0 | +0.0 | false (equal) | `a` (-0.0) |
| +0.0 | -0.0 | false (equal) | `a` (+0.0) |

Note that +-Infinity work fine in comparisons against finite values, so I had to write "non-NaN" rather than "finite".

---

**With `-ffast-math` (to tell the compiler to assume no NaNs, and other assumptions and approximations), compilers *will* optimize either function to a single `minsd`.  https://godbolt.org/z/a7oK91**

For GCC, see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath
clang supports similar options, including `-ffast-math` as a catch-all.

Some of those options should be enabled by almost everyone, except for weird legacy codebases, e.g. `-fno-math-errno`.  (See [this Q&A for more about recommended math optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673825/how-to-force-gcc-to-assume-that-a-floating-point-expression-is-non-negative)).  And gcc `-fno-trapping-math` is a good idea because it doesn't fully work anyway, despite being on by default (some optimizations can still change the number of FP exceptions that would be raised if exceptions were unmasked, including sometimes even from 1 to 0 or 0 to non-zero, IIRC).  `gcc -ftrapping-math` also blocks some optimizations that are 100% safe even wrt. exception semantics, so it's pretty bad.  In code that doesn't use `fenv.h`, you'll never know the difference.

**But treating `std::min` as commutative can only be accomplished with options that assume no NaNs, and stuff like that, so definitely can't be called "safe"** for code that cares about exactly what happens with NaNs.  e.g. `-ffinite-math-only` assumes no NaNs (and no infinities)

`clang -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffinite-math-only` will do the optimization you're looking for.  (unsafe-math-optimizations implies a bunch of more specific options, including not caring about signed zero semantics).

Comment: Some of the details that `-ffast-math` ignores are not that subtle. I was unpleasantly surprised that it optimizes `isnan()` to `false`: https://godbolt.org/z/zs31Yn

Comment: @jpa: Yeah, "subtle" wasn't a great description, except for code where NaN is something that doesn't happen under normal conditions and you aren't trying to handle it.  Edited to be more specific.

Comment: Note that the need for `movapd` is fixed with `-mavx` option (assuming the target CPU supports AVX), since AVX adds non-destructive source (3-operand) coding of the instructions.

Comment: @Ruslan: True.  You could still invent cases where it costs a extra instruction, though, e.g. where one operand is memory like `x = std::min(array[i], x)`.  Even AVX would need a separate load in a loop instead of a memory source operand because only the 2nd source can be memory.  (And it couldn't auto-vectorize with a horizontal min at the end: `std::min` isn't associative either for FP).

Answer (score 14):

Consider: `std::signbit(std::min(+0.0, -0.0)) == false && std::signbit(std::min(-0.0, +0.0)) == true`.

The only other difference is if both arguments are (possibly different) NaNs, the second argument should be returned.

---

You can allow gcc to reorder the arguments by using the `-funsafe-math-optimizations -fno-math-errno` optimsations (Both enabled by `-ffast-math`). `unsafe-math-optimizations` allows the compiler to not care about signed zero, and `finite-math-only` to not care about NaNs

Comment: `-fno-math-errno` should be irrelevant here; `std::min` is a C++ STL template function, *not* a C math library function that historically had errno-setting on NaN semantics like `fmin` or `sqrt`.  `-fno-math-errno` is always a good idea, though, except in historical codebases that check `errno` instead of using `fenv.h`.

Comment: Should be but apparently isn't, with clang9.0.  https://godbolt.org/z/4bdvMa shows that `-funsafe-math-optimizations` alone doesn't do it, but adding `-fno-math-errno` does optimize it as commutative.  This may be a clang9 bug, perhaps also implying a no-NaN assumption that unsafe-math doesn't include?  With clang 10.0 and with GCC, unsafe-math + no-math-errno still preserves the operand-order difference: some other part of fast-math makes the difference.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on the existing answers that say `std::min` isn't commutative: Here's a concrete example that reliably distinguishes `std_min_xy` from `std_min_yx`. [Godbolt:](https://godbolt.org/z/cWK49e)

```
bool distinguish1() {
    return 1 / std_min_xy(0.0, -0.0) > 0.0;
}
bool distinguish2() {
    return 1 / std_min_yx(0.0, -0.0) > 0.0;
}
```

`distinguish1()` evaluates to `1 / 0.0 > 0.0`, i.e. `INFTY > 0.0`, or `true`.
`distinguish2()` evaluates to `1 / -0.0 > 0.0`, i.e. `-INFTY > 0.0`, or `false`.
(All this under IEEE rules, of course. I don't think the C++ standard *mandates* that compilers preserve this particular behavior. Honestly I was surprised that the expression `-0.0` actually evaluated to a negative zero in the first place!

[`-ffinite-math-only` eliminates this way of telling the difference](https://godbolt.org/z/b81Mz7), and [`-ffinite-math-only -funsafe-math-optimizations` completely eliminates the difference in codegen](https://godbolt.org/z/xYPce6).